# Can't debug test cases in ruby mine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rvm, rubymine

I used to debug test cases in ruby mine for my rails test cases. Some time ago I updated my ruby mine and not sure what happened since then, I am not able to debug my test cases.
Attaching the screenshot of the error below:

[image: screenshot-here]

What can be done here to rectify this?

Here is the same console output in plain text:

```
Testing started at 12:53 PM ...
bash -c "/Users/someUSER/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.3.1 do /Users/someUSER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.beta6/bin/rdebug-ide --key-value --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --evaluation-control --time-limit 100 --memory-limit 0 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 49496 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 49497 -- /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rspec /Users/someUSER/RubymineProjects/Proj/spec/controllers/site/some_controller_spec.rb --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter --example \"Site::SomeController Some POST create new data \""

Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.0.beta6, debase 0.2.2, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:49496
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/formatters/fallback_message_formatter
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:132:in `require'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:132:in `setup_default'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:47:in `block in prepare_default'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:228:in `ensure_listeners_ready'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:199:in `notify'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:92:in `message'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:161:in `notify_non_example_exception'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2037:in `rescue in load_file_handling_errors'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2034:in `load_file_handling_errors'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1560:in `block in load_spec_files'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1558:in `each'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1558:in `load_spec_files'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:98:in `setup'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/someUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.beta6/bin/rdebug-ide:187:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1

Empty test suite.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having problems to install the debug gem for RubyMine. I had the same issue and after taking a look at JetBrains web page seems like they are working to fix it on RubyMine 2018.3.3. Meantime, a workaround is to install the gems in a console.

Open the terminal inside RubyMine and run:

```
gem install debase -v 0.2.3.beta3 --no-document
gem install ruby-debug-ide -v 0.7.0.beta7 --no-document
```

Answer (score 0):

The beta6 version of the ruby-debug-ide gem that you use is older than rspec 3.8. Maybe upgrading ruby-debug-ide to the latest beta7 version helps (or downgrading rspec to a version older than beta6).